# Opencv: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm getting this error when trying to capture video from webcam using opencv. This is the code I'm using:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv ) {
    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    IplImage *frame;
    cvNamedWindow("test");

    while ( 1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture) ;
        cvShowImage("test",  frame);
        int key = cvWaitKey(1);
        if ( key == 27 ) break;   // ESC key was pressed
    }

    // Memory deallocation
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("test");

    return 0;
}
```

The error occur at cvShowImage("text", frame):

> OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat,
>   file
>   /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp,
>   line 2382 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

What is it error about and how can I fix it?

Comment: This code should work. Are you sure that the camera is being accessed when you run it?

Comment: Did you run it threw a debugger and make sure that frame and capture aren't null?

Comment: I still study opencv. This code is for learning purpose only and I think the camera (webcam) should be accessible!
Previously, I check and don't know why frame always null

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that whether there is a device at index 0, like this

```
  if (!capture)
  {
      // print error and exit
      cout << "ERROR: Capture is null!\n";
      return -1;
  }
```

Secondly, :

```
while ( capture)
{
     frame = cvQueryFrame(capture) ;
     cvShowImage("test",  frame);
     int key = cvWaitKey(1);
     if ( key == 27 ) break;   // ESC key was pressed
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I check and find that the frame always null. 
Do you think there might be problem with opencv installation? I'm using opencv2.4.6 with mac os 10.8

Comment: You can check the whether the capture is null or not, using the code above. And maybe you should ignore the first frame from `cvQueryFrame`

Comment: the capture is not null. And how can I ignore the first frame

Comment: just put the `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)`before the `while`

Comment: still got the same problem =(